# common sense VS common practice

Tags: meaning

would you explain this quote for me please  :

> "**common sense isn't always common practice**".- Stephen Covey

Comment: Have you tried looking up "sense" and "practice" in dictionaries? If dictionaries don't help, please explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Common sense** means "good sense and sound judgement in practical matters."

It is the logical answer to something, which doesn't take any expertise to know.

**Common practice** is the generally accepted way of doing something, or the most widely used option.

It is what the majority of people do in a situation.

> **"common sense isn't always common practice"**

The literal meaning of this, therefore, is "The logical answer isn't always what most people do."